# enabling users to modify documents stored by an application

Tags: c#, .net, file, filesystems

we have the following scenario:

* a .NET application allows users to upload documents.

* the documents are stored in a filesystem, currently inaccessible to users. the path is basically \year\month\day\filename.ext

* the path and filename are stored in a database (MS SQL200) that is used to link the documents to various records in the system

the question:

how to implement a situation where:

we maintain the link between the files and the records

we allow users to modify the files and to access them easily

we prevent situations where the files and the db would become unsynchronized.

it has to be as user friendly as possible (e.g. no "download the file, modify and upload it again")

Thanks for any hints and pointers to a direction
Matej

Comment: See answer below by Andrew.. you are describing SharePoint

Comment: Please mention if you cannot use commercially available Document Management Systems such as SharePoint because of the licensing cost (or some other reason) - otherwise using a DMS is the right thing to do

Comment: SharePoint is free with a license for Windows Server 2003 or higher.

Comment: no, no DMS is being used. until now, all the files have been just stored and downloaded/e-mailed. No modification necessary. The system is in place and has been used for several years. now we need to adopt to a change in use. Of course, we are not closed to using a product if it's implementation and cost would be a good alternative to our own solution.

Comment: please be aware that any DMS usage project has to contain uploading the current files while keeping links to the correct records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew said (+1), you should to consider Sharepoint. That would be my first option.

If you still need to do it from scratch, your filesystem folder will need to have their ACL permissions restricted for a unique user, controlled by your application (maybe your application pool user). This user, and only this, is allowed to manipulate that documents. Or you can consider to store them in your database, just like Sharepoint does.

You'll need to deal with users uploading files with same name in same day.

To download them, you can start by implementing a `IHttpAsyncHandler`; it's starts trivial, but get complicated very easily.

Answer (score 7):

Before you reinvent the wheel, have you considered [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/product/details/Pages/default.aspx)?